# NVME slower on host than in VM

Tags: hard-disk, performance, io, ssd, nvme

I first noticed some strange performance hits when I switched from Vagrant to Docker for my local development setup.

After investigating why my databases were slower in this new environment, I came to the conclusion that Docker wasn't really the problem. In fact, my NVME SSD (Samsung 970 EVO Plus) seems just faster in a Vagrant VM than it is on the host... and I have no idea why.

I ran the same sysbench fileio test in a VM and on the host.

**Host:**

```
sysbench fileio --file-total-size=40G prepare
42949672960 bytes written in 42.35 seconds (967.12 MiB/sec).
```

**VM:**

```
sysbench fileio --file-total-size=40G prepare
42949672960 bytes written in 26.71 seconds (1533.36 MiB/sec).
```

*Then:*

**Host:**

```
sysbench fileio --file-total-size=40G --file-test-mode=rndrw --max-time=20 --max-requests=0 run

Running the test with following options:
Number of threads: 1
Initializing random number generator from current time


Extra file open flags: (none)
128 files, 320MiB each
40GiB total file size
Block size 16KiB
Number of IO requests: 0
Read/Write ratio for combined random IO test: 1.50
Periodic FSYNC enabled, calling fsync() each 100 requests.
Calling fsync() at the end of test, Enabled.
Using synchronous I/O mode
Doing random r/w test
Initializing worker threads...

Threads started!


File operations:
    reads/s:                      943.15
    writes/s:                     628.73
    fsyncs/s:                     2012.27

Throughput:
    read, MiB/s:                  14.74
    written, MiB/s:               9.82

General statistics:
    total time:                          20.0357s
    total number of events:              71688

Latency (ms):
         min:                                    0.00
         avg:                                    0.28
         max:                                   17.35
         95th percentile:                        1.03
         sum:                                19934.06

Threads fairness:
    events (avg/stddev):           71688.0000/0.00
    execution time (avg/stddev):   19.9341/0.00
```

**VM:**

```
sysbench fileio --file-total-size=40G --file-test-mode=rndrw --max-time=20 --max-requests=0 run

Running the test with following options:
Number of threads: 1
Initializing random number generator from current time


Extra file open flags: (none)
128 files, 320MiB each
40GiB total file size
Block size 16KiB
Number of IO requests: 0
Read/Write ratio for combined random IO test: 1.50
Periodic FSYNC enabled, calling fsync() each 100 requests.
Calling fsync() at the end of test, Enabled.
Using synchronous I/O mode
Doing random r/w test
Initializing worker threads...

Threads started!


File operations:
    reads/s:                      2173.40
    writes/s:                     1448.94
    fsyncs/s:                     4637.65

Throughput:
    read, MiB/s:                  33.96
    written, MiB/s:               22.64

General statistics:
    total time:                          20.0136s
    total number of events:              165193

Latency (ms):
         min:                                    0.00
         avg:                                    0.12
         max:                                   11.10
         95th percentile:                        0.45
         sum:                                19902.66

Threads fairness:
    events (avg/stddev):           165193.0000/0.00
    execution time (avg/stddev):   19.9027/0.00
```

Does anyone have an idea about what can cause this behavior and/or what can be tested ?

Comment: Have you enabled host side cache for the VM though? And how do you pass the drive to the VM? One of the virtio approach of vfio (pcie passthrough)?

Comment: To be honest i'm not very familiar with all the VM terminology, this VM is from Laravel Homestead. It is a "plug and play" virtual machine for local development, almost no configuration needed (install, map the directories, vagrant up and you are ready to go). However, the directories used to prepare (and run) the tests were not the same (one was created inside the VM itself, the other was somewhere else on the host). The VM performances seem closer to what is expected from a NVME SSD than what I measure from the host, don't you think ?